# Why can you have statefulness inside a static class in java?

Tags: java, static

I was playing around with Java today and I read about static inner classes. Why can you have 'statefulness' inside of a static inner class. For instance:

```
class outerClass { 
        static class Test { 
        private String a; 

        String getA() { return a; } 

        void setA( String newA) {a = newA; } 

    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something? It seems like you should not be able to keep mutable state inside of a class that is labled at static. Moreover it seems like you should not be able to instantiate something that is a static class, it should be a static singleton. Perhaps someone could correct me if I am making an incorrect assumption or enlighten me to why the Java authors decided to make this possible.

EDIT: I feel as if I am confusing the keyword `final` and `static` in java, as `final` variables do not have state. It still seems *very* strange to be able to instantiate a static class, though.

Comment: `static` on a nested class means that the class doesn't need to maintain a pointer to its enclosing outer class. It *doesn't* mean that all fields and methods must be `static`, as with `abstract`. Different keyword, different behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static inner class is the same as a non-inner class. Your example is equivalent to:

```
class outerClass {}

class Test {
    ...
}
```

The `static` in static inner classes means that instances of the inner class aren't associated with an instance of the outer class. Without `static`, an instance of `Test` is always attached to an instance of `outerClass` - you'd need to construct an instance of `outerClass` before you can construct an instance of `Test` and the instance of `Test` would have access to the members of `outerClass`.

Answer (score 4):

`static` things aren't always stateless.  Instead, `static` refers to the ability to access the instance variables and methods in an object.

With [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in Java, the `static` modifier on the inner class refers to its access to the outer class.

A `static` inner class does not have access to the instance variables of its enclosing class (just like a `static` method doesn't have access to the instance variables).  A further implication of this is that because the static inner class doesn't have the ability to access the instance variables it can be instantiated separately from the outer class. However, there is nothing in this definition that implies the lack of state.

The reason to use a `static` inner class is to further encapsulate it so that it can't tinker with its outer class member variables or methods.

---

With a later edit and some confusion about static, final and state:

> I feel as if I am confusing the keyword `final` and `static` in java, as final variables do not have state. It still seems very strange to be able to instantiate a static class, though.

I must point out that final variables have state too. It is just a state that can be assigned once and only once.  Consider:

```
final int foo;
if(bar) {
    foo = 42;
} else {
    foo = 4;
}
```

Perfectly valid and stateful code on a final variable.

A static inner class that you can't instantiate is a situation that I can't quite find a use case for. Yes, the Java designers used `static` in yet another way (import, class, block, field, method, and inner class too). Each different use of `static` is distinct and should be considered to be separate concepts that sometimes interact.

In this case, the `static` *inner* class is more akin to a `static` method than a `static` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep static state.  It is just associated with the class, rather than with the object instance.  So every object instance sees the same state value.

Comment: That's not really true for the nested class, is it? In the example above, you *can* have different instances of `Test` with different values for `a`. They just can't access any hypothetical non-static members of `outerClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The *keyword* "static" in Java just means objects of that class are not tied to the enclosing class.  It has *nothing* to do with static methods and fields.  A static class is even more normal than a normal Java nested class.

You may be thinking in terms of the C# static class, which does not allow state, and contains only static members.  (C# *is* a bit more consistent with the term.)  I have heard people, even when talking about Java, refer to classes with no state as "static", so it pays to check what people mean when they use the term.

If you are familiar with C#, be aware that, deep down, Java and C# are very different languages, and their superficial similarities will trip you up badly if you're not careful.